# R igraph: label vertex by condition

Tags: r, label, igraph

I have a graph g with a set of vertices and a list with the names of some "special" vertices.
I want the graph to display a label with the vertex name ONLY for these special vertices.

I tried something like this:

```
plot(g, vertex.size = 4, vertex.label = ifelse(V(g) %in% usernames, V(g)$label, ""), asp = F)
```

But apparently I'm missing something, because the predicate never enter TRUE.
Also, it seems like V(g)$label results in the following error:

> Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] : replacement has length zero

Your help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's best practice to provide a minimal reproducible example, ready to copy paste run, instead of loose code snippets and unreproducible error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Turn `V(g)` into `V(g)$label`?

```
set.seed(1)
library(igraph)
g <- ba.game(26)
V(g)$label <- letters[1:26]
usernames <- sample(letters, 5)
plot(g, vertex.label = ifelse(V(g)$label %in% usernames, V(g)$label, NA))
```

or

```
set.seed(1)
library(igraph)
g <- ba.game(26)
usernames <- sample(vcount(g), 5)
plot(g, vertex.label = ifelse(V(g) %in% usernames, V(g), NA))
```

?

Comment: Hey Luke, I applied your solution and it works great! I just have a question, what about when you have 2 dfs where you have "labels of interest" and you want to plot it in your graph? I tried with `plot(subgraphGRN, vertex.label1 = ifelse(c(V(subgraphGRN)$name %in% nodes_query, V(subgraphGRN)$name %in% res.subg$Names), V(subgraphGRN)$symbol,NA),
     layout = layout.sphere(subgraphGRN)` but it is not really working... any suggestions?